# How to play Multiplayer in Little Big Planet 2

Tags: ps3, little-big-planet-2

I have completed 5 levels of Little Big Planet 2, but I can't seem to access any items on the pod menu except story.  I also cannot accept any invitations from friends.  Is there something I need to complete to be able to play multiplayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the value is for Little Big planet 2 but in the first game you had to finish a certain number of single player levels to unlock online play.

I think this is basically to make sure everyone playing is at a reasonable standard when they start playing with other players so that games flow better rather than waiting for a player who doesn't understand how to get past a certain obstacle.

Comment: This is not the case in Little Big Planet 2.  I could play online from the initial load up.

Comment: @Corv1nus Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Corv1nus, did you have a LBP1 save?  I think those with the first game had access to community from the start.  As I found out last night after playing a couple of levels, Fishcake is right.